# MVC Scaffold in ASP MVC4 throws error when visiting page (open data reader & multiple connections)

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4

I have generated an entity (City) and now I tried to generate the scaffolding with MVC Scaffold according to this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/468777/Code-First-with-Entity-Framework-5-using-MVC4-and

The issue I'm having is that I'm doing this on a MySQL server, and I get the following error:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection
>   which must be closed first.

I looked around and noticed that some people had to enable MARS (Multiple Active Result Sets) in their connectionstring, but apparently MySQL has no such parameter. I also tried AllowBatch=True but that didn't work either. Here's my connectionstring:

```
<add name="socialgeogroep6Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;AllowBatch=True;user id=socialgeogroep6;password=snow;database=socialgeogroep6&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Has anyone had this issue before, and if so, how did you solve it? I'd really appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: this could be a number of issues. first mysql only supports 1 connection. 2nd users often run into issues when they try to bind IEnumberable lists b/c it keeps the reader open. Please include your Controller and View code

Comment: Hi @DaveA, thank you for the reply. I made pastebins of the code:

Controller: http://pastebin.com/QX4rTQFs
View: http://pastebin.com/1837hrMp (this one is the index view)
The generated entity: http://pastebin.com/Tcpvbkp3

I noticed that if I go to for example cities/Detail/5 that that page DOES work. I can also go to the edit page. Another problem though is that it doesn't render the country choices as a dropdown list but just gives me an input for numbers (so for the ID). Isn't that what MVC Scaffold is all about?

Comment: from the post I found, I would say changing the bind type to LIST<> instead of IEnumerable will 'close' the reader. Football overwhelmed my day, but ill look into your code and check why scaffold for dropdown fails tmrw.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem due to lazy loading being enabled. You didn't post the repository code, but I wonder if this query is causing the problem:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View(cityRepository.AllIncluding(city => city.users, city => city.districts));
}
```

I use the `Include()` statement to perform eager loading to get one or two sub-entities in one query. If we say there's a function called `All()` in the repo that returns an `IQueryable`, one could do something like this:

```cs
    // ...
    var allCities = cityRepository.All().Include("users").Include("districts").ToList();
    return View(allCities);
}
```

This would create a query that selects all `cities` along with their `users` and `districts` navigation properties populated, all at once. The `ToList()` will perform the query and return an `IEnumerable` as opposed to an `IQueryable`, which would be enumerated by lazy loading, once the properties are accessed in the consuming code.

If it was a different repository function causing this problem, working `Include()` into it in a similar fashion should be straightforward.